# How do I ensure all running processes start again after I restart my ec2 instance upon resizing it?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I want to ensure that all the currently running processes and services start again or that I know a list so that I can start them again after restarting my ec2 instance. I need to restart my ec2 instance because I need to resize it(and it has to restart after resizing)

I tried using htop and making a list manually. I don't think that would be a great idea.

Comment: same as any ubuntu - list the services with correct ps command then add them as services or part of a script that is run when computer starts

Comment: how would i list the services when i dont know the exhaustive list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680050/how-do-i-install-chkconfig-on-ubuntu This might help you.